# Issue with Typeahead.js using DOM content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, typeahead.js

I'm trying to design a little application that navigation will work with storing html markup (generated with javascript making queries on local database) and then storing an array for AppHistory...

I have several options, when user clicks specifics option a little form with one input (linked with typeahead) and a button will be displayed, for example:

The options are: Programming Languages, Countries, Color, etc...

If the user selects "Programming Languages" he will see the little form with the input (that will be populated with a query  - `SELECT names FROM proglangs`) and the button. With Typeahead if the user write "jav" in the input, the options "**Jav**ascript" and "**Jav**a" will be listed. Then if the user click the button item informations will be displayed, in this case the specific programming language selected.

The problem occures when I go back! When the users goes back the content is loaded again but I think the query is not performed or the `link` with Typeahead get losts.

How can I do to solve this? Thanks for reading and please forgive my bad english!